# How to use VS Code's SQLTools extension to log in to a SQL Server database with domain credentials

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, sqltools

I can successfully use SQL Server Management Studio and Python (via SQLAlchemy) to access a database. I would like to use VSCode's SQLTools extension to do the same. Below are my settings

### These methods work

SQL Server Management Studio:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server Type | `Database Engine` |
| Server name | `Server1.subdomain.domain.com` |
| User name | `userdomain\userid` |
| Password |  |

Python with SQLAlchemy

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Connection string | `mssql+pymssql://userdomain\userid:password@Server1.subdomain.domain.com/database` |

### These methods do not work

VSCode using connection string:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Connection string | `mssql+pymssql://userdomain\userid:password@Server1.subdomain.domain.com` |

This throws an error

> The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string

VS Code using server and port:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Connection name | `Connection1` |
| Connect using | `Server and Port` |
| Server Address | `Server1.subdomain.domain.com` |
| Username | `userdomain\userid` |
| Password | `Ask on connect` |

This throws an error

> Login failed for user 'userdomain\userid'

I've also tried using `userid` for "username", without `userdomain`.

Comment: try it this way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @nbk I tried following the instructions using the following connection string (`server=server.subdomain.domain.com;database=database1;Integrated Security=false;User ID=userdomain\userid;Password=password`), but I get a warning and an error. Warning: [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver16#encrypt-and-trust-server-certificate) . Error: `mssql: Error 18456: Login failed for user 'userdomain\userid'.`

Answer (score 0):

The connection sting is a normal one, like the ones for ADO.NET

```
server=mydbserver;database=mydatabase;Integrated Security=false;User ID=domain\username;Password=your_pass
```

you need to remove the integrated services from the string, which are for windows authetification

```
server=mydbserver;database=mydatabase;User ID=username;Password=your_pass
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but then I get this error: `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.` I tried without `userdomain`, but then it just says `Login failed for user 'userid'.`

Comment: remove the integrated service and the domain from the user name

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried with and without the domain.

Comment: your error message says that you have the wrong credentials, so try the connction with ssms and see if you get it to run

Comment: also the statement  with username and passwort needs that the server accepts sql and windows authentification, and you need the same username added as user withe the necessary rights

Comment: Regarding the credentials, as I mentioned in my post, I am able to successfully connect to the server and all databases using MS SQL Management Studio and Python via SQLAlchemy. Do you have any other troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: not really when you can access the database with ssms sql authentification, you can alos with the sql tools, they use similar functions

Comment: I've been trying this on macOS. For comparison I tried on Windows and it also doesn't work. I also tried Azure Data Studio (macOS) and it doesn't work. On MS SQL Management Studio I tried `SQL Authentication` and `Active Directory - Password` and I get a login error. However, `Windows Authentication` works, as does Python with SQLAlchemy using the same credentials.

Comment: then the sql serve is wrong configured change it see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16